# How do I extract fiscal month number from a date column using SQL and without using case statements

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

currently I'm extracting the month numbers using case statements like below

```
WHEN cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date)  >= cast('2019-12-29' as date) AND cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date) <= cast('2020-02-01' as date) THEN 1
WHEN cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date)  >= cast('2020-02-02' as date) AND cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date) <= cast('2020-02-29' as date) THEN 2
WHEN cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date)  >= cast('2020-03-01' as date) AND cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date) <= cast('2020-03-28' as date) THEN 3
WHEN cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date)  >= cast('2020-03-29' as date) AND cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date) <= cast('2020-05-02' as date) THEN 4
WHEN cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date)  >= cast('2020-05-03' as date) AND cast(estimated_arrival_datetime as date) <= cast('2020-05-30' as date) THEN 5
```

But is there a better way to extract the month numbers also the date column will also include 2021 data

EDIT : Using Redshift

Comment: [Edit] your question, please, to tell us the make and version of your server. There's wide variety in date handling among them.

Comment: Sorry just updated, the question, I'm using redshift so I believe that's postgresql

Comment: @KaranKashyap . . . I don't understand the logic.  Your question is about extracting month numbers, but your code seems to be doing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't seem to support ISO months directly.  You can convert from ISO weeks:

```
(case when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '04' then 1
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '08' then 2
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '13' then 3
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '17' then 4
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '21' then 5
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '26' then 6
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '30' then 7
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '34' then 8
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '39' then 9
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '43' then 10
      when to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW') <= '47' then 11
      else 12
end)
```

This should work for any year.

Comment: Thank you for this and just curious if I want to extract the week numbers using the same logic above, what difference in the code will I need to make?

Comment: @KaranKashyap . . . The week number is what is being used:  `to_char(estimated_arrival_datetime, 'IW')`.